# How to measure kafka reBalance duration

Tags: apache-kafka, aws-msk

is there tool available to measure Kafka re-balancing duration? or check any intermediate status?

we have observe  a many time, specific consumer get stuck forever during Kafka rebalancing, we never waited to finish.

Answer (score 0):

There was a [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-9752) in Apache Kafka `2.4.1` which got fixed, and [MSK has 2.4.1.1](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/09/amazon-msk-now-offers-version-2-4-1-1-fixing-a-perpetual-rebalance-bug-in-apache-kafka-2-4-1/). This was exactly related to infinite rebalance of consumers.

If your MSK running later versions, you can open support case.

Comment: is there tool available or statistics within Kafka to know if if Kafka ReBalance occured?

Comment: in MSK, broker logs will have rebalance trace. you can analyze the logs by delivering them to Splunk, Elastic/Open-Search, etc... or even pushing to firehose with lambda.